# having a HANDLE to a Process how to sign up for monitoring of its close/restart/duplication event?

Tags: c++, winapi

Having a handle tpo a process like so:

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
    PROCESS_VM_READ,
    FALSE, processID );
```

How to sign up for this  process update events - like close\restart? Is it possible to sign up for duplication event (start up of second same process)?

Comment: There is no api in Windows to 'duplicate' a process.  So no way to ask for an event for it either.  You can use WMI to get process startup notifications, Win32_ProcessStartTrace class.

Answer (score 1):

Process handles are signaled when the process they represent exits. So to find out when the process exits, you can pass `hProcess` to `WaitForSingleObject` or any other wait function.